# Returning a value on exception

Tags: asp.net, exception, asp.net-2.0

Why does this code not compile?
It gives me the error:

> not all code paths return a value

#### Code:

```
public bool isUserProfileHashed(string username)
{
    bool isHashed = false;
    MembershipUser u = null;
    u = Membership.GetUser(username);
    if (u != null)
    {
        try
        {
            u.GetPassword();                   
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // An exception is thrown when the GetPassword method is called for a user with a hashed password
            isHashed = true;
            return isHashed;
        }
        return isHashed;
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

You forgot to put a return **outside** of the if, put it after the if ending brace

```
public bool isUserProfileHashed(string username)
{
    bool isHashed = false;
    MembershipUser u = null;
    u = Membership.GetUser(username);
    if (u != null)
    {
        try
        {
            u.GetPassword();                   
        }
        catch
        {
            // An exception is thrown when the GetPassword method is called for a user with a hashed password
            isHashed = true;
        }
    }
    return isHashed;
}
```

**[Edit]**
Remove unnecessary return (@Fredrik Mörk)
Caught exception not used hence removed it as well.

Comment: You are probably aware of it already, but you could actually remove the return statment in the catch-block as well; it doesn't add anything.

Answer (score 1):

There is no return statement outside of the if block. Sometimes that if block may not execute.

Answer (score 1):

No return if u is null.

Answer (score 1):

If u == null, your entire if-statement will be **skipped over**. There is no return statement outside of your if statement.

That is why you see, "**not all code paths return a value**."

Just add a return statement after your if block:

```
public bool isUserProfileHashed(string username)
{
    bool isHashed = false;
    MembershipUser u = null;
    u = Membership.GetUser(username);
    if (u != null)
    {
        // ...
        return isHashed;
    }

    // more code here if you need it

    return ??? ; // <--- **ADD THIS**
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not handling the case where `u == null` and returning a value if that condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

If **u** happens to be **null** you don't return!

This should work better

```
public bool isUserProfileHashed(string username)
{
    bool isHashed = false;
    MembershipUser u = null;
    u = Membership.GetUser(username);
    if (u != null)
    {
        try
        {
            u.GetPassword();                   
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // An exception is thrown when the GetPassword method is called for a user with a hashed password
            isHashed = true;
            return isHashed;
        }
        return isHashed;
    }
    else
    { 
        //Throw or return false, whatever
        throw new Exception("Could not get user ...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correction to your method has been noted by other posters, however, would it be possible to replace the entire method with this line?

```
if(Membership.Provider.PasswordFormat == MembershipPasswordFormat.Hashed)
```